# Why am i getting too many arguments error in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Actually that script was working fine previously, I don't know how suddenly that too many arguments error came up.

```
Table_name[0]="Emp_table"
For index in "${!Table_name[*]}"; do
Tname="$Table_name[index]"
if [ -f $Tname*.* ]; then
Rm $Tname*.*
fi
done
```

Here error comming at the if statement.
The same script logic working fine previously, I started implementing the same logic in new script, that time this error came up for both scripts,
I am new to this shell scripting.
Could some one help me understand.

Comment: Note that `Tname="$Table_name[index]"` is not correct shell syntax. To retrieve an element of an array, you need `${Table_name[index]}` (with the braces). See [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual

Comment: Why are you checking for file existence at all?   Just do `rm -f "$Tname"*`.  If the files don't exist, it's a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

the `test`, `[` and `[[` commands all act the same in that
they do different things based on *how many arguments they are given*
(excluding the closing `]`/`]]`).

- with 1 argument, the test will be successful if the argument is not empty
- with 2 arguments, the arguments are treated as a unary operator (such as
  `-n`) and an operand.
- with 3 arguments, the arguments are treated as an operand, a binary
  operator (such as `=`) and another operand
- more than 3 arguments, `test` and `[` give a "too many arguments" error,
  and `[[` may or may not give an error (it has a more complicated parser).

`-f` expects a single argument to tell you if that is a file.

`$Tname*.*` is expanding to multiple arguments.

---

I think you want to know: are there any files that *start with* `$Tname`. Here's one way:

```bash
files=( "$Tname"*.* )
if [ ${!files[@]} -ge 1 ] && [ -f "${files[0]}" ]; then ...
```

That captures the list of files in the `files` array, and then tests the size of that array.

Comment: The only thing to be wary here is that the array size can be 1 even if there are no matches unless `nullglob` is set on account of a non-matching glob evaluating to itself. Maybe check whether the first match _actually exists_?